# Не закрепляются значки на рабочем столе

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

Система linux-mint 18.2 mate
У меня на рабочем столе много значков и раньше они все время находились на тех местах, где я их поставил, а с некоторых пор при перезагрузке они все упорядочиваются. Мне это не удобно, потому что значков много и после такого упорядочивания трудно найти необходимый. 
Как можно закрепить значок на том месте, где его поставил?

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема обсуждалась на [форуме Linux Mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=229544). Убедитесь, что все файлы на рабочем столе принадлежат вам (что у вас есть права доступа к каждому из них).

Comment: чтобы долго и нудно не «убеждаться», можно сразу поменять: `$ sudo chown -R "$(id -nu):$(id -ng)" "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"; chmod -R u+rw "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"`